# Align number beside glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot seem to get this number to align inline to the glyphicon. I want the number 3 to be pushed up more so that it lines up.

**CSS**

```
body {
        background-image: url("bg1.png");
}
.icons {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.well blockquote {
  border-color: #ddd;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.well-lg {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.well-sm {
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#alertbox {
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        text-align: center;
}
#topicon {
        font-size: 50px;
}
#stats {
        font-size: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well well-lg">
           <div id="alertbox" class="alert alert-info">Total APIs</div>
           <span id="topicon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>
           <span id="stats">3</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

using the positioning doesnt work when scaling since the number 3 would go into the center when on a mobile phone. I need it to auto-scale i guess for smaller browsers.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the float from `#stats`, you could do something like this:

```
.well {text-align: justify;}
.well:after{content:""; width: 100%; display: inline-block; height: 0;}
span {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: It works but then I get a huge gap under the glyphicon and number 3.